# Missing 'stdout' file when using Slurm and Singularity

Tags: slurm, singularity-container, nextflow

I want to use Nextflow for creating pipelines of singularity components which will be executed by Slurm job scheduler.
I created a simple job to run just a single task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

process createGroups {

  executor = 'slurm'
  queue = 'upgrade'
  memory = '10 GB'
  time = '30 min'
  cpus = 8
  clusterOptions = '--workdir /path/to/the/singularity/image'
    """
    singularity run ...
    """
}
```

The job executes successfully and gives exit status 0, but Nextflow arises "Missing 'stdout' file" error. There is the full output:

```
Error executing process > 'createGroups'

Caused by:
  Missing 'stdout' file: .../work/89/449f849ffc77a967be91ed994da860/.command.out for process > createGroups

Command executed:
executor >  slurm (1)
[89/449f84] process > createGroups [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
Error executing process > 'createGroups'

Caused by:
  Missing 'stdout' file: .../work/89/449f849ffc77a967be91ed994da860/.command.out for process > createGroups

Command executed:

  singularity run ...

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)

Work dir:
  .../work/89/449f849ffc77a967be91ed994da860

Tip: when you have fixed the problem you can continue the execution adding the option `-resume` to the run command line
```

I couldn't find any solution to fix this error :(

Update:
Using the slurm's --workdir parameter caused that error. I simply used "cd" command to change the path and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to avoid calling Singularity manually, like in your script block. Assuming Singularity will be in your $PATH on every execution/compute node in your queue, then, all you'd need, for example, is:

In your `nextflow.config`:

```
process {

  executor = 'slurm'
}

singularity {

  enabled = true
  cacheDir = '/path/to/containers'
}
```

Then, your nextflow script would look like:

```
process bwa_mem {

    container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/bwa:0.7.17--h5bf99c6_8'

    queue = 'upgrade'

    cpus = 8
    memory = '10 GB'
    time = '30.m'

    """
    bwa mem
    """
}
```

See also: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/singularity.html

Comment: Thanks Steve for your response, it seems this error is not related to using singularity, I tried to run a simple command e.g. "echo hello" and it gives me the same error: Missing 'stdout' file: .../.command.out for process > createGroups

Comment: @PouyaAhmadvand: Haven't seen that one before, but found it has already been reported: https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/780. Just curious, what version of Bash are you using? You may need a newer version.

Comment: It's weird the bash version I'm using is greater than 4.2 in both the execution/compute node, and I still get this error :( I got the bash version by using this command: bash --version

Comment: @PouyaAhmadvand: What about the version of Bash inside your container? E.g.: `singularity exec quay.io-biocontainers-bwa-0.7.17--h5bf99c6_8.img bash --version`. Or are you also hitting this error when you run jobs without Singularity?

Comment: I found what caused that error I was using clusterOptions attribute and pass --workdir to Slurm, removing that line solved my problem. But I'm wondering is it any way to change the working directory and use Nextflow without any error?

Comment: I just simply used "cd" command to change the path to the location of the singularity image and it solved my problem. btw it's weird using --workdir slurm parameter causes that error. Thanks @Steve for your help :)

Comment: No worries at all @PouyaAhmadvand. That is strange, but I don't think you should need to change directories just to use Singularity images. Have you tried setting a Singularity cacheDir (like in the example above) and ignoring the `--workdir` option?

Comment: The thing is that I'm using the singularity to run python codes and I don't include the python files in the singularity. My singularity definition file look likes this: 
`%runscript
    python app.py $*` and the `app.py` and other dependencies are located at the singularity image directory. So I need to change the working directory to that directory to get the code working.

Comment: @PouyaAhmadvand So Nextflow runs Singularity containers using `singularity exec`, see [how it works](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/singularity.html#how-it-works). I'm not sure how 'exec' works with a 'runscript' statement exactly. I think it might just ignore it, but I'm not sure entirely. Is there some reason you can't include the python dependencies in your container? All you'd need to do is copy them using the [`%files` definition](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/definition_files.html#files).